# PHP CURL isn't processing encoded return data properly

Tags: php, http, curl, encoding, utf-8

Im have some minor encoding issues. Im getting a json data string from here (try it yourself):

```
http://cdn.content.easports.com/fifa/fltOnlineAssets/C74DDF38-0B11-49b0-B199-2E2A11D1CC13/2014/fut/items/web/179899.json
```

The name in the data is shown like this

```
Ari SkÃºlason
```

How can I fetch this data with proper encoding so its Ari Skúlason?

I tried switching it to utf-8 like this in php

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($r,'ISO-8859-1','utf-8');
```

which got me closer, but its still not right

```
Ari Sk�lason
```

my php curl request:

```
$location = 'http://cdn.content.easports.com/fifa/fltOnlineAssets/C74DDF38-0B11-49b0-  B199-2E2A11D1CC13/2014/fut/items/web/179899.json';
$ch = curl_init($location);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                                                                                                        
'Accept: application/json'));
$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo mb_detect_encoding($r);
$r = mb_convert_encoding($r,'ISO-8859-1','utf-8');

print_r($r);
```

Comment: do you have control on the url the your are CURLing with? you can change the encoding there

Answer (score 33, accepted):

set another curl option for  `CURLOPT_ENCODING` and set it to "" to ensure it will not return any garbage

```
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING ,"");
```

Answer (score 9):

You Can use header

```
   header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

and after decode string

```
 $page = utf8_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

It's worked for me

or

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

after add this

```
$page = curl_exec($ch);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($page, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: Whether it works or not, UTF-8 is not a valid argument for CURLOPT_ENCODING. This specifies the Accept-Encoding Field, and has nothing to do with character encoding. Valid arguments are: identity, gzip, deflate and "".

Comment: I had different response for the same URL when request from CURL or from Browser. Lots of thanks for light me about CURLOPT_USERAGENT... now it works fine in both :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also try.

...

```
$results = curl_exec($init);
curl_close($init);
return json_decode(utf8_encode($results));
```

utf8_encode encoded ASCII character. Returning a non-encoded ASCII may break or return an error (In my case).

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$res= curl_exec ( $ch ); 
$result = iconv("Windows-1251", "UTF-8", $res);
```