# Mandrill API Error

Tags: php, mandrill

First Time i used Mandrill API to send email,

But I got this error.

A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_ValidationError - You must specify a key value
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mandrill_ValidationError' with message 'You must specify a key value' in mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php:153 Stack trace: #0 mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php(132): Mandrill->castError(Array) #1 mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill/Messages.php(80): Mandrill->call('messages/send', Array) #2 mandrill.php(88): Mandrill_Messages->send(Array, false) #3 {main} thrown in Mandrill.php on line 153

This is my code

```
<?php

require_once 'mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php';

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$table = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);


if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}



$selected = mysql_select_db("DB Name")
    or die("Could not select database");

$query=mysql_query(Query);


$table .= "<table width='auto'  height='auto' border='1'  bordercolor='#003399'  style='color:#FF0000;table-layout:fixed' cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<th>User ID</th>
<th>Full Name</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Email ID</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{ 
$table .= "<tr>";
$table .= "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
$table .= "<td>" . $row['fullname'] . "</td>";
$table .= "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
$table .= "<td>" . $row['useremail'] . "</td>";
$table .= "</tr>"; 
}
$table .= "</table><br>";


try {
$mandrill = new Mandrill(API Key);
$message = array(
    'html' => $table,
    'subject' => 'Notification Email',
    'from_email' => 'Example@example.com',
    'from_name' => 'Test',
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'Example@example.com',
            'name' => 'Test',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
    ),
    'important' => false,
    'track_opens' => null,
    'track_clicks' => null,
    'auto_text' => null,
    'auto_html' => null,
    'inline_css' => null,
    'url_strip_qs' => null,
   // A mandrill error occurred: Mandrill_Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
throw $e;
}
?>
'preserve_recipients' => null,
    'view_content_link' => null,
    'tracking_domain' => null,
    'signing_domain' => null,
    'return_path_domain' => null,

);
$async = false;
$result = $mandrill->messages->send($message, $async);
print_r($result);


} 
catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {

echo 'A mandrill error occurred: ' . get_class($e) . ' - ' . $e->getMessage();

throw $e;
}
?>
```

Comment: That isn't even valid PHP...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17700002/mandrill-validationerror

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>/*
Before coding, you have to make configurations in Mandrill.

Step 1: Enter Mandrill and register your domain.

Step 2: Configure DNS: DKIM and SPF (This is a good tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEjP_smeLjU) at https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-domains

Step 3: Get a KEY API (https://mandrillapp.com/settings)

Step 4: Code with PHP

Step 5: Good luck! :)
*/


/*LIBS*/
include 'lib/mandrill-api-php/src/Mandrill.php';
$mandrill = new Mandrill('YOUR API KEY HERE');

/*ADMIN AND USER EMAIL*/
$admin_email = 'your_email@your_domain.com';
$client_email = 'the_email_of_the_client@mail.com';

/*attach PDF*/
$attachment = file_get_contents('the_route_to_your_pdf');
$attachment_encoded = base64_encode($attachment);

try{
    $user_message = array(
        'subject' => 'Your Subject here',
        'from_email' => $admin_email,
        'from_name' => 'your_domain_for_example',
        'html' =>  '<p>Aquí va la plantilla HMTL</p>',
        'to' => array(array('email' => $client_email, 'name' => 'Recipient 1')),
        'merge_vars' => array(array(
            'rcpt' => 'recipient1@domain.com',
            'vars' =>
            array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'FIRSTNAME',
                    'content' => 'Recipient 1 first name'),
                array(
                    'name' => 'LASTNAME',
                    'content' => 'Last name')
            ))),
        'attachments' => array(
            array(
                'content' => $attachment_encoded,
                'type' => "application/pdf",
                'name' => 'the_name_of_the_attach.pdf',
            ))
    );

    $res_user_mandrill = $mandrill->messages->send($user_message, $async=false, $ip_pool=null, $send_at=null);

} catch(Mandrill_Error $e) {

}

</pre>
```